# How to create web application in android?

Tags: java, android

Hi i am fresher in android 
I want to create web application for an existing website ...
similar to apps like  facebook  and flipkart 
can anyone help me ....

Comment: This is not a site to post question like yours. I would suggest that you start doing some research on your own, and then if you have a specific question come back and ask. You can get started by doing the android tutorials: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: I know all the android basics but i don't how to fetch and update details on a webpage

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways one is Building Web Apps in WebView

refer [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

also refer [Web Apps Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing web app your best bet is to use a framework like [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). It lets you keep most of your JS/HTML code.